# Datastore delay on creating entities with put()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am developing an application using with the [Cloud Datastore Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) (2.1.0) and the [google-cloud-ndb](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-ndb/) Python library (1.6).

I find that there is an intermittent delay on entities being retrievable via a query.

For example, if I create an entity like this:

```
my_entity = MyEntity(foo='bar')
my_entity.put()

get_my_entity = MyEntity.query().filter(MyEntity.foo == 'bar').get()
print(get_my_entity.foo)
```

it will fail itermittently because the `get()` method returns `None`.

This only happens on about 1 in 10 calls.

To demonstrate, I've created this script (also available with ready to run docker-compose setup on [GitHub](https://github.com/LondonAppDev/cloud-datastore-example)):

```py
import random

from google.cloud import ndb
from google.auth.credentials import AnonymousCredentials


client = ndb.Client(
    credentials=AnonymousCredentials(),
    project='local-dev',
)


class SampleModel(ndb.Model):
    """Sample model."""
    some_val = ndb.StringProperty()


for x in range(1, 1000):
    print(f'Attempt {x}')
    with client.context():
        random_text = str(random.randint(0, 9999999999))
        new_model = SampleModel(some_val=random_text)
        new_model.put()

        retrieved_model = SampleModel.query().filter(
            SampleModel.some_val == random_text
        ).get()
        print(f'Model Text: {retrieved_model.some_val}')
```

What would be the correct way to avoid this intermittent failure? Is there a way to ensure the entity is always available after the `put()` call?

**Update**
I can confirm that this is only an issue with the datastore emulator. When testing on app engine and a Firestore in Datastore mode, entities are available immediately after calling `put()`.

Comment: Does it happen if you fetch the entity via its `id` or `key`?  For example `SimpleMOdel.get_by_id(<some-id>)` or `entity.key().get()` (check the syntax, I haven't used the datastore for a while)

Comment: @snakecharmerb just tested and no the issue doesn't present if using `SampleModel.get_by_id(int_id)`... This makes me think that the issue is a delay in indexing. I wonder if there is a way to force the indexing to happen?

Comment: It might be trying to simulate eventual consistency?

Comment: @snakecharmerb just looked that up and there is a flag `--consistency` which can be set to `1.0` to turn that off... However the issue still persists.

Comment: Correction: I didn't apply the change properly... `--consistency=1.0` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be related to the emulator trying to replicate eventual consistency.

Unlike relational databases, Datastore does not gaurentee that the data will be available immediately after it's posted. This is because there are often replication and indexing delays.

For things like unit tests, this can be resolved by passing `--consistency=1.0` to the `datastore start` command as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start).